# Double appending \\ in a byte string python

Tags: python, string, byte

I'm trying to convert a hex string `\x11\x22\x33\x44\x55` to a byte string where it should become `b'\x11\22\33\44\55'`. I'm aware of `byte.fromhex()` however, this causes `\x22` to be output as " which changes my output to a false positive.

I've tried converting a string `\x11\x22\x33\x44\x55` to byte string by using `str.encode(bytestring)` however, this causes the string to become `b'\\x11\\x22\\x33\\x44\\x55'`. Again, giving a false positive.

Is it possible to transfer the hex string into bytes so it just displays as `b'\x11\x22\x33\x44\x55'`?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> cause `\x22` to be output as " which changes my output to a false
> positive.

This pertains only to *display* consider that

```
print(b'\xFF\x22\xFF' == b'\xFF"\xFF')
```

output

```
True
```

Comment: I understand it's true. However, for my encryption- I need it to be strictly \x22. Else it won't work. I've created a manual byte array of b'\x11\x22......' and it works. However, I would like file inputs so I can read and encrypt from a file.